# VC++ unit test project failed to set up the execution context to run the test due to possible missing dll

Tags: c++, unit-testing, objectarx

VC++ Newbie here:

I am attempting to TDD a project that uses a third party library (specifically AutoDesk's ObjectARX).

I have been able to create a dummy solution with a unittest project and a helloworld ARX project. I can successfully test a dummy method, everything is cool.

But when I call anything from the ObjectARX libraries the unit tests fail with

```
Failed to set up the execution context to run the test
```

After digging about and using Dependency Walker I found that the compiled dll is not able to find `acdb21.dll` which is named the same as one of the ARX libraries.  It's expecting to find it in the same folder as the compiled dll.

I do not have an `acdb21.dll`, only the `.h` and `.lib` files. My understanding is that they should be compiled into the dll.

The linker happily finds the `.h` and `.lib` files so AFAICT the include and library paths are all set correctly.

Is the missing dll reported by Dependency Walker a red herring? Is something else amiss?

Comment: When you say "you don't have acdb21.dll", can you get a copy? If so, try just putting it in the same dir as the test exe as an interim step.

Comment: Thanks, @doctorlove out of frustration I opened the .lib in a hexeditor and found references to acdb21.dll.  Wasn't expecting that, I knew that some .libs are wrappers for dlls but this lib was large enough to look like a stand alone library.  I think I'll try and find away of implementing the header and use a fake.